# Email Template - Block Repeat

Tags: marketing-cloud, template

I am trying to come up solution where one can have a repeating block in a template. So then user can add as many blocks. For example

```
<table>

<block>

<tr><td>adasdasd</td</tr>

</block>
```

I trying to figure out how do I make a block repeated, without hard coding x times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Content Builder**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/content_builder/getting_started_with_content_builder/) allows for this by default.

You code the content areas differently in your template, but the result is that you can stack Content Builder content in a single Content Area.